# How to adjust the appearance of formatted references

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, harvard-style

I am currently writing a paper and need to use referencing. The requirement is to use the Harvard style referencing. I have got a Harvard style bibliography with BibTeX. The output in my reference list is as follows:

[image]

But what I'd like to have is:

[image]

I am currently using the `natbib` package with the `dcu` bibliography style:

```
...
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
This a test \citep{catal2009investigating}.
%%%%%%
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

I've tried other bib styles from the `harvard` package, including `agsm`, `jmr`, `apsr`, etc. But that doesn't work. Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. compilable code:Starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also add the bib file.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting to emphasize the focus on the way bib entries are formatted. Generally, "harvard style", which is also known as author-year style, is an attribute of the citation call-outs, *not* the formatted bib entries. What may be confusing things here is that the `harvard` *package* offers various bib styles (such as `dcu`, `agsm`, `jmr`, etc) which affect both the way the citation call-outs and the bib entries are formatted.

Comment: Could you consider using `biblatex`? It's easier to customise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But a few tweaks, the `agsm` bibliography style comes very close to your desired formatting. I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `agsm.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of the file and name the copy, say, `agsm-mod.bst`. (Don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `agsm-mod.bst` in a text editor. (The program you use to edit tex files will do fine.
- In `agsm-mod.bst`, replace all four [4] instances of `" \harvardand\ "` with `" and "`. (Note the whitespace before and after `and`.)
- In the same file, in the `article` function (which begins around line 690 of the file), locate the following line:

  ```
        " " * format.vol.num.pages * output
  ```

  In this line, delete the substring `" " *`. I.e., the line should now read

  ```
        format.vol.num.pages * output
  ```
- Locate the function `format.vol.num.pages`; its code should start around line 355, and it should be about 20 lines long. Replace the entire function with the following code:

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
  { ", Vol.~" volume * field.or.null
    number empty$
      'skip$
      { ", No.~" number * "" * *
        volume empty$
      { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
      'skip$
        if$
      }
    if$
    pages empty$
      'skip$
      { duplicate$ empty$
      { pop$ format.pages }
      { ", pp.\ " * pages n.dashify * }
        if$
      }
    if$
  }
  ```
- Save the file `agsm-mod.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystye{<whatever>}` to `\bibliographystyle{agsm-mod}`. Then, rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
%% bib info from https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1502817.1503027
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{catal-diri:20097,
 author  = {Catal, Cagatay and Diri, Banu},
 title   = {Investigating the Effect of Dataset Size, Metrics Sets, and 
            Feature Selection Techniques on Software Fault Prediction Problem},
 journal = {Information Sciences},
 volume  = {179},
 number  = {8},
 year    = {2009},
 pages   = {1040--1058},
} 
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm-mod}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Many thanks for your concise revisions and help!